# Inaccessible folders

Tags: directory, shared-folders

I have some folders on a second hard disk, that I can't access from Ubuntu, but I can from Windows.

[image: Folder properties]

[image: Folder properties]

Comment: You can't add screens just yet, but if you attach links, we can edit them as images. If you get reputation, you will be able to do so too.

Comment: Relevant bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/1728354

Comment: I think this will be your problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/982742/how-to-read-onedrive-ntfs-folder-in-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, it is OneDrive folders. I am stuck with this error message when trying to install: ~/Downloads/onedrive$  ./configure
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in build-aux "."/build-aux

Comment: Got over the hurdle thanks to this: https://github.com/plashchynski/libdssl/issues/4

Comment: Error when configuring: ./configure: line 13148: syntax error near unexpected token `LIBNTFS_3G,'
./configure: line 13148: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBNTFS_3G, libntfs-3g >= 2016.2.22AR, ,'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86381/discussion-between-shmu-and-meskobalazs).