# How to read Synology Drive NTFS folder in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, ntfs-3g

Hi I'm on a dual boot system with Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I have a ntfs partition that I installed Synology Drive Client on. The idea is for me to reach this folder from both Windows and Ubuntu. The ntfs partition is mounted using `ntfs-3g` and works as it should, however the SynologyDrive folder is inaccessable. It shows as a broken symlink. See image:[image]

Synology Drive Client 2.0.1-11061

I tried to compile the `Onedrive` plugin as per [How to read OneDrive NTFS Folder in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982742/how-to-read-onedrive-ntfs-folder-in-ubuntu) thinking maybe it's a similar situation, but I got stuck at `E: Unable to locate package libntfs-3g`. But I'm actually fairly sure it was working before under Ubuntu, I just can't figure out what broke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is because of a feature called 'On Demand Sync',

> On-demand Sync is an option for configuring Synology Drive sync task between a computer and your Synology NAS, and is currently available on Windows 10 version 1809 and above. While regular synchronization tasks sync an identical copy of files to your local computers, On-demand Sync only syncs file lists to your local computers. The files are downloaded to your local computers only when you open, modify, or pin a local copy to your computer.

source: https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Collaboration/What_is_On-demand_Sync

What I had to do is (in Windows) unlink the current `SynologyDrive` folder to Synology Drive Client, create a new connection and uncheck the 'On Demand Sync' option. That new folder became available for me in Ubuntu.